# Intermittent connection problems for some users on StrongSwan VPN gateway

Tags: vpn, strongswan

We have a VPN gateway using StrongSwan U5.9.10 and Rocky Linux 9.2 with 5.14.0-284 x86_64 kernel serving total of <200 Windows users. Split-tunneling is used.

StrongSwan configuration was migrated from an old machine, thus it's using legacy non-swanctl configuration scheme.

The problem is that for a fraction of users the VPN connection is unstable. They're being disconnected after a few seconds up to few tens of minutes.
On the old machine (Linux strongSwan U5.3.5/K3.10.17-smp) everything worked properly.

The configuration is:

```
#ipsec.conf

config setup
         uniqueids=yes

conn %default
        ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes128-sha256-modp1024
        esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha1

conn windows
        keyexchange=ikev2
        dpdaction=clear
        dpddelay=300s
        ikelifetime=14400s
        rekey=no
        left=[gateway_wan_ip]
        leftid=[gateway_fqdn]
        leftsubnet=10.16.0.0/16
        leftauth=pubkey
        leftcert=strongswan.pem
        leftsendcert=always
        right=%any
        rightsourceip=10.16.100.0/24
        rightauth=eap-mschapv2
        rightsendcert=never
        compress=no
        fragmentation=yes
        eap_identity=%any
        auto=add
```

There are some errors in **/proc/self/net/xfrm_stat**:

```
  XfrmInNoStates                  1
  XfrmInStateProtoError           1298
  XfrmInStateSeqError             17
```

Audit log indicates SA-icv-failures as @ecdsa mentioned in his comment.

What we've tried:

- increasing charon.replay_window to 128. That lowered XFRM error counters, but problems persist,
- adjusting MTU/MSS as described [here](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/howtos/forwarding.html#_mtumss_issues),
- ruling out WAN interface problems on the gateway.

Nothing really helped and now I'm stuck. Where to dig next?

Comment: What do the XFRM errors have to do with your statement of "They're being disconnected after a few seconds up to few tens of minutes"? Are they actually disconnected or are you only referring to the dropped ESP packets? Also, increasing the replay window can really only affect the sequence number errors, not the protocol errors, which could be from packets with invalid ICVs (the Linux audit log can show details on this).

Comment: Because I don't have very good understanding of XFRM I just posted the errors hoping it would clarify the situation. Clients' VPN actually disconnects. Previously XfrmInStateSeqError counter was in tens of thousands, hence replay window increase.

Comment: If they actually disconnect, you'll have to look at the logs.